# Regex to match domain/u & domain/u/username but not domain/user

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The title  says it all, but I will explain a bit more:

The following **should** be matched:

> - domain/u                     =   domain/user.html
> - domain/u/usermame  =    domain/user.html?u=username
> - domain/u/                    =   domain/user.html

The following **should not** be matched:

> - domain/user
> - domain/u(any other character(s) here e.g. universe | uvwxyz)

---

I have got close, but I cannot work out how to only match if it is followed by nothing or a slash, And if it is followed by a slash catch whats after the slash.

I'm trying to use mod_rewrite in a .htaccess to turn `domain/user.html?u=xxx` into `domain/u/xxx`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
^domain\/u($|\/$|\/(?<username>.+)$)
```

The user name is captured by the named group `username`

Comment: I think we're getting somewhere, But If there is no username (`domain/u`) it throws a 404. It does, however, work when there is a username

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, It is as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^http://www.example.com\/u(\/(?<username>.+)$) user.html?u=username [L]
RewriteRule ^(u/$|u$) user.html [NC,L]
```

As you may have noticed, the first line is from CyberDude's answer, I added the second line to prevent example.com/u & example.com/u/ from simply 404'ing